# How do I use remote function with check_box_tag in rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

It's a checkbox used for todo list.

Before I used

```
 <%= link_to "Finished!", finish_task_path(feed_item), :method=>:put,:remote=>true%>
```

with a piece of javascript in finish.js

```
 $('#task_<%= @task.id %>.task').fadeOut();
```

Now instead of using

```
link_to
```

I want to use

```
check_box_tag
```

So every time user clicks on checkbox, it should make the entry fade out

I tried

```
 <%= check_box_tag 'finish[]',feed_item.id,false,:onchange => remote_function(:url=>finish_task_path(feed_item),:method=>:put, :before => "$('#task_#{feed_item.id}').show();", :complete => "$('#task_#{feed_item.id}').hide(); ") %>
```

but it doesn't work, and I also don't know how to use

```
:with =>
```

here.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using jQuery. That means you should be using UJS. So get all those inline JavaScript calls out of your code! Instead, give your checkbox tag a class, and in your layout, make sure you include the js file that contains some JavaScript:

```
$('.myCheckBoxClass').click(function() {
  // Make your AJAX call, and then...
  var id = // Traverse the DOM to get your feed_item id
  $('#task_' + id).hide();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

did you know that jQuery and Prototype are enemies, so first put jQuery.noConflict(); check this jQuery link [link text](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/).

Comment: But I didn't include Prototype?

Comment: Prototype is included when you set up your javascript_include_tag :defaults code snippet. check RubyOnRails documentation. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html and look for javascript_include_tag